# Label_attr canot be set in configureOptions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Update:
In a new installation of 2.8.3 a minimal set of files (template, controller, entity, form type) are added and the issue remains.  `config.php` reports no problems with installation. Installation is in Windows 10 Pro, 32-bit. Files are shown below.

Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use AppBundle\Form\MemberType;

/**
 * @Route("/member")
 */
class MemberController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="member_edit")
     * @Template("Member/edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function editMemberAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $member = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new MemberType(), $member);
        return [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'member' => $member,
        ];
    }

}
```

Form type:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class MemberType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('fname', TextType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'First name',
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Member',
            'label_attr' => ['style' => 'font-weight: bold;'],
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'member';
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="member")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Member
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fname", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Member first name may not be blank")
     */
    protected $fname;

    /**
     * Set fname
     *
     * @param string $fname
     * @return Member
     */
    public function setFname($fname)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFname()
    {
        return $this->fname;
    }

}
```

Template:

```
{{ form_row(form.fname) }}
```

Original question:

A form type with a `label_attr` set in `configureOptions` is ignored, but is rendered when appearing in the field's spec.  Symfony is 2.8.3.  Curiously, a different app also in 2.8.3 does NOT ignore `label_attr` in `configureOptions`.  So it's unlikely the difference is not in the following code, but here it is:

Field in form:

```
        ->add('fname', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'First name:',
        ))
```

configureOptions:

```
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member',
            'required' => false,
            'label_attr' => ['style' => 'font-weight: bold;'],
        ));
    }
```

template extract:

```
{% for member in form.members %}
    {{ form_row(member.fname) }}
...
{% endfor %}
```

What is NOT causing this behavior, i.e., tests performed:

- a form theme
- any CSS file
- any JS file

Comment: May be second application has form extension that copies `label_attr` from form to elements. Or element is adding not as `TextType::class`, but custom form type that defines `label_attr` in `configureOptions`.

Comment: @Max P. Interesting thought.  I did a search of the `src` directory - no other mentions of `label_attr`.  Cleared the cache, just in case.  No luck.  I've confirmed that Twig's label widget is used by temporarily adding `{{ dump(label_attr) }}`.  This causes `[]` to be rendered when `label_attr` is in `configureOptions`.  When in the field spec I get the expected result.  There are no TwigExtensions in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class MemberType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('fname', TextType::class, array(
                    'label'      => 'First name',
                    'label_attr' => $options['label_attr'],
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Member',
            'label_attr' => ['style' => 'font-weight: bold;'],
            'required'   => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'member';
    }
}
```

This is only a small improvement over **T30**'s solution. If you want an option to be inherited from a compound form over all its children, you have no choice but to tell the child it inherits it.

Symfony's inheritance of form types is not a compound / compounded relationship, think of it more as some sort of class inheritance.

Comment: I find this difficult to accept - other options set in `configureOptions`, e.g., `'required' => false`, do not require a similar `'required' => $options['required']`.  Is there documentation to support your answer?

Comment: I find I must accept your answer.  There appears to be nothing in FormBuilder to apply default options unless they are explicitly included in the `->add()` method.  Adding to the `$options` array simply makes values available rather than applying them.  All along Ive wrongfully assumed they were applied.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: You're welcome. It will get clearer once you've got some practice with the framework, but the form component specifically is notoriously one of the harder components to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move `label_attr` in the `buildForm` method? Something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('fname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'First name',
                'label_attr' => ['style' => 'font-weight: bold']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that `label_attr` works only when part of the field `add()`.  The docs claim `label_attr` is an inherited option, and a dump of `$options` at the top of the `buildForm()` function shows that `label_attr` exists and is modified when included in defaultOptions.  Yet it is not applied when the template is rendered.  I want to be able to apply a label attribute to all labels at once rather than repeat the code for each field.

Comment: What the doc means by "inherited" is not what you think. All form types are organized in a hierarchy, i.e. the `EntityType` form type (from Doctrine) inherits from the `ChoiceType` form type, meaning if you were to change the default data of `ChoiceType` this would have an impact on all `EntityType` fields used in your app.

Comment: @Zephyr Form inheritance I understand.  How does this apply to the default options within a given form type?  This sounds like saying, "Here are the options to use on this form (setting a value in `configureOptions`), and yes, I'm really serious so use them (adding the option again in `add()`),"